# how to use web_hook for doing POST Rest API to a server from promrtheus alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using the following configuration for alertmanager for sending API post call for prometheus but somehow I am not able to get it, below is my configuration

with my flask server running on localhost at port 9000, that accepts a POST API call

`global:
    http_config: 'http://localhost:9000'
route:
 group_by: ['alertname']
 group_wait: 30s
 group_interval: 10s
 repeat_interval: 10s
 receiver: test_api
 routes:
  - receiver: test_api
    group_wait: 10s
    match:
        infra_grp: pse
receivers:
- name: "test_api"
  webhook_configs:
    send_resolved: true
    url: '/test/test_host'`

Answer (score 1):

That is an invalid configuration. Remove the global section and try:

```
 receivers:
 - name: "test_api"  
   webhook_configs:
     send_resolved: true
     url: 'http://localhost:9000/test/test_host'
```